# Apache CentOS HTTP Test Page displays - but only for my specific browser

Tags: apache, safari, centos

A client's website was working fine, until they had some problems with their web host. Temporarily, the Apache CentOS Test Page was visible. The host claim the problem is fixed - and it seems to be - for everyone but me...

I'm using Safari 7 on OS X Mavericks and every single time when I visit their site I still see the test page.

- When anyone else uses their own computer with any browser, it works fine...
- When I use Chrome on my Mac it works fine... So the problem is just with Safari.
- I've tried clearing Safari's cache
- I've tried clearing the DNS cache
- I've tried a restart

But I've got no idea why I can't access it. I need to access the site to work on it - yes I can use Chrome, but Safari is my primary browser. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was caused by an issue in a Regex within Apache's Mod_Security. The Regex falsely identified a string contained within a cookie as being an SQL injection (it wasn't - purely coincidental).